# How can I get funding for my research article?

Tags: funding, open-access

An article of mine has been accepted by a Springer journal.

I want to publish this article in Open Access.
My institute is a pretty small one and cannot fund my research. Is there any worldwide funding agency I can approach? I am from India.

Comment: Sometimes journals offer reduced or free rates according to economic circumstances in different countries, but you have to check with the individual journal. We don't allow questions asking for specific journals/institutions/funding agencies ("shopping questions").

Answer (score 2):

I assume that you mean have Springer post it as open-access. Otherwise you have to get copyright permission from them. But they may be willing to waive fees (or reduce them) if you ask and plead poverty.

I haven't dealt with Springer on this but some professional societies will waive fees in such situations, especially for small institutions that don't normally produce a lot of publications.

But funding for papers, rather than research projects, is pretty rare. If you have the opportunity to apply for grants for research, keep this in mind and include a portion in the grant request for publishing fees of the results of the research. Too late in this case, of course.

Comment: In fact, it is pretty common by now (at least for European grants) to have part of the funding for open access. In fact, the EU pushes for open access publishing.

Comment: @user151413, yes, if you have a grant to charge against. I think the OP does not in this case.

Answer (score 1):

You can contact Springer directly about this, they have an "OA funding support service" who can inform you about your options.

From https://www.springeropen.com/about/oa-funding-and-policy-support:

> In partnership with our parent publisher, Springer Nature, we offer a free open access (OA) support service to make it easier for authors to discover and apply for funding for OA publication charges for articles, books, and book chapters.
>
> To use this service, visit our OA support pages and discover our lists of organizations which offer funding for article processing charges (APCs) or book and chapter processing charges (BPCs/CPCs). Here you can also find further OA funding and policy guidance, including a checklist and FAQs to help with securing funding and meet the requirements of funders’ and institutions’ OA policies.
>
> For further advice on the funding available to you and guidance in approaching funders and institutions, please contact us at OAfundingpolicy@springernature.com.